# Use mongo $cond aggregator to generate a new field in the first occurrance of a value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections:

```
{
"Sku" : "A",
"Stock" : [
    {
        "StoreCode" : "1",
        "Qty" : 3
    }
 ]
},
{
"Sku" : "B",
"Stock" : [
    {
        "StoreCode" : "1",
        "Qty" : 3
    },
    {
        "StoreCode" : "2",
        "Qty" : 5
    },
    {
        "StoreCode" : "10",
        "Qty" : 7
    }
 ]
}
```

And

```
{
"Sku" : "A",
"MinQty" : 2
}
{
"Sku" : "B",
"MinQty" : 5
}
```

How can I aggregate this two collections to get the below expected output:

```
{
"Sku" : "A",
"Availability" : "in stock"
}
{
"Sku" : "B",
"Availability" : "out of stock"
}
```

Basically, If one store of a specific SKU doesn't have the `MinQty` in stock, the availability of the product is "out of stock". All stores need to have the minimum quantity (`MinQty`) in stock.

I did this using lookup, unwind and joining again the unwinded data.

Is there a simple way to do this using $cond iterating through `Stock` in the first collection:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can try this query:

- First `$lookup` to "join" the fields by the `sku` value.
- Then a `$project` stage to output values you want.
- Using `$cond` where you can add the stages `$gte`, `$max` and `$min`.

And if I'm not wrong the logic is: "if (`$cond`) the minimum (`$min`) number in stock is greater or equal (`$gte`) than the maximum (`$max`) number in`MinQty` then is "in stock", otherwise "out of stock".

```
db.collA.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collB",
      "localField": "Sku",
      "foreignField": "Sku",
      "as": "skus"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "Sku": 1,
      "Availability": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gte": [
              {
                "$min": "$Stock.Qty"
              },
              {
                "$max": "$skus.MinQty"
              }
            ]
          },
          "then": "in stock",
          "else": "out of stock"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D1OzBlzNlD9)